# Delete single item from cart using remove button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to delete a specific item from the cart when clicking on a button called remove. This is the code I have currently.

```
    String productName = request.getParameter("product");
    
    String r = request.getParameter("remove");

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("cart") == null) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("cart", new ArrayList<Product>());
    }
    
    if (productName != null) {
        Product p = manager.getProduct(productName);

        if (p.getName().equals(productName)) {

            List<Product> cart = (List<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
            cart.add(p);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("cart", cart);

        }  else if (p.getName().equals(r)){
            List<Product> cart = (List<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
            cart.remove(p);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("cart", cart);
        } 
        
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/checkout.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

The debug tells me that the remove parameter is null.

Comment: Hi, how does `servlet` gets called ? Where is your form  code ?